# Wordpress - Wrap every 2 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 columns blog and I want to wrap every 2 posts using row class, so i try:

```
<?php $counter = -1; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <?php $counter++;?>
    <?php if ($counter % 2 == 0) : ?>
        <?php echo '<div class="row">'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/two-columns', get_post_format() );?>
    <?php
    if ($counter % 2 != 0) : ?>
        <?php echo '</div>'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

but if I have 2n+1 posts on page I can't close div - this part of code doesn't work

```
if ($counter % 2 != 0) : ?>
    <?php echo '</div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually answered your questions already by yourself with `this part of code doesn't work`
You want to open the `<div>` and close it on the same condition...

```
<?php $counter = -1; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <?php $counter++;?>
    <?php if ($counter % 2 == 0) : ?>
        <?php echo '<div class="row">'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/two-columns', get_post_format() );?>
    <?php if ($counter % 2 == 0) : ?>
        <?php echo '</div>'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: but i want to wrap 2 posts in div, but if 1 post i cant wrap it

Comment: @namename2 I don't think you can achieve that with the "normal" loop. You will get more attention with this question if asking here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ also add the comment you wrote to me to the question. Let me know, then I will delete the answer and you can if you want delete the question.